# Expand/Collapse a div from one height to other height

Tags: javascript

I have a div with style

```
#thumb {
  position:absolute;
  top:365px;
  left:280px;
  z-index:0;
  width:500px;
  text-align:left;
  height:235px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now I am using javascript function to expand and collapse

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   var v = document.getElementById("viewall");
   if (e.style.overflow != 'visible')
   {
      v.innerText= "Collapse";
      e.style.overflow = 'visible';
   }
   else
   {
      v.innerText= "Expand";
      e.style.overflow = 'hidden';
   }
}
```

But I don't want to just overflow it.. I want to increase the height of div when expanding and return back to height 235px when you collapse it.

How can I do that? I am newbie to javascript..Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Put the collapsible content in a separate `<div style="display:none">`  and just set `display:block` when you want to expand it

Comment: Don't do what GregGuida said. Look into css Transitions, they will help you with the animation you need.

Comment: Actually the div thumb element is asp repeater control. It displays several images and in my case I am displaying some of images in the page load say 10 images before expand. When you click on expand it should show all the images. I can do it by toggling visible and hidden. But I have div under the thumb div. When thumb is overflow:visible it is covering the beneath div. So how can I resolve this. Apology for my language. please let me know need any info and pleas help me in this.

Answer (score 2):

hmm, did you try using this to set the height?
it should work i think.

```
document.getElementById('idhere').style.height = divHeight+'100px';
```

where the number before the px is how much you want to add the height, use minus to take away height. also idhere is where you put in the id of the div. does it work?

Comment: Thank you TheEliteNoob.. It does work in normal cases ..I am in different situation. Actually the div thumb element is asp repeater control. It displays several images and in my case I am displaying some of images in the page load say 10 images before expand. When you click on expand it should show all the images. I can do it by toggling visible and hidden. But I have div under the thumb div. When thumb is overflow:visible it is covering the beneath div. So how can I resolve this. Apology for my language. please let me know need any info and pleas help me in this.